# Socket.io в Node.js 4

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Привет всем. Так вышло, что я недавно начал разбираться с Node.js и socket.io, и еще многого не понимаю, но тут вышла новая версия Node.js - четвертая и там появился класс `Net.socket` (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/). Является ли он включением в себя socket.io или альтернативой? Я както слышал, что их хотели объединить. Стоит ли начинать сейчас новые проекты с использованием socket.io?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Net.Socket` - это абстракция TCP сокета в Node.js и он не имеет ничего общего с `Socket.io`.

Вы не правы, говоря что `Net.Socket` появился только в версии 4.0.0. Он был доступен и в более ранних версиях Node.js. Например, вот [здесь](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) есть документация по этому классу для Node.js 0.12.x.